# Copy output after job has crashed

Tags: error-handling, crash, cluster-computing, hpc, qsub

I have a simulation running on a cluster. I submit jobs with a `qsub` script that looks like

```
#PBS directives

#function to copy data
copy_data()

... stuff ...

./my_simulation
copy_data
```

However if the simulation crashes the output is not copied back. How can I handle errors in the executable? And in general how do I force the job to copy back the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start with this one:

```
function handle_signals {
  echo "Signal caught! Cleaning!"
  # do some stuff here
  echo "Done!"
}

trap handle_signals SIGTERM
trap handle_signals SIGSEGV
```